# Line filtering from text file using filter in Python

Tags: python

Trying to filter out commented lines using filter before executing qualified lines on sqlplus but doesn't seem to work, any help would be appreciated.

```
import re
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    allsqls = f.read()
    sqlcmds = allsqls.split(';')
    print(sqlcmds)
searchpattern = re.compile(r'^(?!--|\n).*', re.M)
sqls1 = list(filter(lambda x: searchpattern.search(x),sqlcmds))
print(sqls1)
sqls2 = list(filter(searchpattern.search,sqlcmds))
print(sqls2)
```

Here is the sample text file -

```
sqlcmd1;

sqlcmd2;


--sqlcmd3;

sqlcmd3;

sqlcmd4;

--sqlcmd5;
--sqlcmd5;
sqlcmd5;
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the `;` in your example test.txt not sure if just forgot.

I'm not expert on regex and think many people would find better solloution.

```
import re
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    allsqls = f.read()
    sqlcmds = allsqls.split('\n')
searchpattern = re.compile(r'^(?!--).*')
sqls1 = list(filter(lambda x: searchpattern.search(x) and x,sqlcmds))
print(sqls1)
```

Comment: right, forgot to put ; in test file. Thanks for pointing that out.